# problem in using select2 in my laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, jquery-select2, laravel-livewire

[image: select2 not working good and do not know why]

my link stylesheet is

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/dashboard-rtl/">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open%20Sans:300,400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="{{ asset('assets/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open%20Sans:300,400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="{{ asset('assets/dist/css/dashboard.rtl.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('assets/dist/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@livewireStyles
```

and script tags are

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/feather-icons/4.24.1/feather.min.js" integrity="sha384-EbSscX4STvYAC/DxHse8z5gEDaNiKAIGW+EpfzYTfQrgIlHywXXrM9SUIZ0BlyfF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha384-i+dHPTzZw7YVZOx9lbH5l6lP74sLRtMtwN2XjVqjf3uAGAREAF4LMIUDTWEVs4LI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="dashboard.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAkeLMlsiwzp6b3Gnaxd86lvakimwGA6UA&callback=initMap"></script>    
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
@livewireScripts
@stack('scripts')
```

and my view is

```
<form class="form-horizontal" wire:submit.prevent="storeServices"> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">اختار العيادة</label><br/>
            <div class="col-md-4" wire:ignore>
                <select class="selectClinic form-control" name="clinics[]" multiple="multiple">
                    @foreach($clinics as $clinic)
                        <option value="{{$clinic->id}}">{{$clinic->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">اختارالخدمات</label><br/>
            <div class="col-md-4" wire:ignore>
                <select class="form-control" name="services[]" id="selectServices" multiple="multiple">
                    @foreach($services as $service)
                        <option value="{{$service->id}}">{{$service->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">حفظ</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

the view must not be like this there is no feel for select2 in my laravel view file and do not understand the reason for this i tried alot of things and have the same problem

Comment: can you share the js select2 init instance?

Comment: You need to initialize `Select2` like [`$("select").select2();`](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage)

Comment: @push('scripts')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.selectClinic').select2();
        });
    </script>
@endpush

Comment: Are there any messages regarding this in the developer console? What happens when you paste in the console `$('.selectClinic').select2();` ?

Comment: The browser does not feel using select2 and react as using normal select